# NGRX sequiental call actions from component

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, ngrx

I'm trying to make a sequiental requests to ngrx-store to save two different entities in two random mongodb collections and need to have answer from first ngrx-store effect to use data in another one on create entity referring to first one.

What I have:

reducer

```
export interface UserState {
  currentUser: IUser | null;
  checkUserResult: any | null;
  user: IUser | null;
  users: IUser[] | null;
  errorMessage: string | null;
  isLoading: boolean;
  isLoaded: boolean;
  isError: boolean;
}

export function userReducer(
  state = initialUserState,
  action: fromUser.UserActions
): UserState {
  switch (action.type) {
    case fromUser.USER_CREATE: {
      return {
        ...state,
        isLoading: true,
      };
    }
    case fromUser.USER_CREATE_SUCCESS: {
      return {
        ...state,
        user: {
          _id: action.user._id,
          userLogin: action.user.userLogin,
          userPassword: action.user.userPassword,
          userEmail: action.user.userEmail,
          userPhone: action.user.userPhone,
          userRole: action.user.userRole,
          userType: action.user.userType,
          userRef: action.user.userRef,
        },
        checkUserResult: null,
        errorMessage: null,
        isLoading: false,
        isLoaded: true,
        isError: false,
      };
    }
    case fromUser.USER_CREATE_FAILURE: {
      return {
        ...state,
        errorMessage: "Can not create user",
        isError: true,
      };
    }

[...]
}
```

action

```
export class UserCreate implements Action {
  readonly type = USER_CREATE;
  constructor(public payload: IUser) {}
}
export class UserCreateSuccess implements Action {
  readonly type = USER_CREATE_SUCCESS;
  constructor(public user: IUser) {}
}
export class UserCreateFailure implements Action {
  readonly type = USER_CREATE_FAILURE;
  constructor(public error: string) {}
}
```

effect

```
@Effect()
  createUser$: Observable<Action> = this.action$.pipe(
    ofType(UserActions.USER_CREATE),
    map((action: UserActions.UserCreate) => action.payload),
    exhaustMap((payload) => {
      return this.userDataService.createUser(payload).pipe(
        map((data) => {
          return new UserActions.UserCreateSuccess(data);
        }),
        catchError((err) => of(new UserActions.UserCreateFailure(err)))
      );
    })
  );
```

selector

```
export const getUserState = createSelector(
  fromFeature.getAppState,
  (state: fromFeature.AppState) => state.users
);
```

and service

```
createUser(user: IUser) {
    this.store.dispatch(new fromStore.UserCreate(user));
    return this.store.select(fromStore.getUserState);
  }
```

as well as another service (user-data.service.ts) which methods calls from effect

```
createUser(user: IUser): Observable<IUser> {
    const url = `${this.BASE_URL}/user/create`;
    return this.http.post<IUser>(url, { ...user });
  }
```

all this setup works while I create only one entity from component

```
user-create.component.ts

onCreateUser() {
    this.us
      .createUser({
        userLogin: this.createUserForm.value.userLogin,
        userPhone: this.createUserForm.value.userPhone,
        userEmail: this.createUserForm.value.userEmail,
        userPassword: this.createUserForm.value.userPassword,
        userRole: this.createUserForm.value.userRole,
        userRef: this.createUserForm.value.userRef,
        userType: this.createUserForm.value.userType,
      })
      .subscribe((user) => {
        if (user) {
          this.createUserForm.reset();
          this.router.navigate(["/users"]);
          this.us.getUsersList();
        }
      });
  }
```

Other logic to create different entities are equal to listed above. And when I try to call action inside action within component like this

```
this.us
      .createUser({
        userLogin: this.createContactUserForm.value.userPhone,
        userPhone: this.createContactUserForm.value.userPhone,
        userEmail: this.createContactUserForm.value.userEmail,
        userPassword: this.createContactUserForm.value.userPassword,
        userRole: this.createContactUserForm.value.userRole,
        userRef: this.createContactUserForm.value.userRef,
        userType: this.createContactUserForm.value.userType,
      })
      .subscribe((userState) => {
        if (userState.user) {
          this.cs
            .createContact({
              contactFirstName: this.createContactUserForm.value
                .contactFirstName,
              contactLastName: this.createContactUserForm.value.contactLastName,
              contactPatronymicName: this.createContactUserForm.value
                .contactPatronymicName,
              contactPhone: this.createContactUserForm.value.userPhone,
              contactUserId: userState.user._id,
            })
            .subscribe((contactState) => {
              if (contactState) {
                this.router.navigate(["/contacts"]);
              }
            });
        }
      });
```

it works as intended, but later, when I try to make any other action - it brokes application state. For example I can't edit or delete contacts after it.
On other hand if I split logic to two independent calls - it won't work, because at moment when createContact method calls - application didn't know yet createdUser _id or userState.user._id and throw an error.

I think, here must be a more complex logic, but how make it correct - I have no clue. Please, suggest me proper way to perform this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have issues related to your subscription management.

The things that I will recommend to you are more like a general idea of how you should work with `NGRX`

First, let's look at your "dispatcher" service / model or however people are calling the service that takes care of dispatching actions nowadays.

```
createUser(user: IUser) {
    this.store.dispatch(new fromStore.UserCreate(user));
    return this.store.select(fromStore.getUserState);
  }
```

Having a separate method to call the `store` is good practice, returning the store selector from there, not so much. There are two reasons for that:

- First the possibility of a case where you want to get the data that is already stored inside the store, without loading it again is very high.
- Second The possibility of wanting to dispatch an action without the need of a subscription to a particular field from the store is also very high.

Refactored version

```
user$ = this.store.select(fromStore.getUserState);
createUser(user: IUser): void {
    this.store.dispatch(new fromStore.UserCreate(user)); 
  }
```

Now let's take a look at the component where you are initiating the create user request

```
user-create.component.ts

onCreateUser() {
    this.us
      .createUser({
        userLogin: this.createUserForm.value.userLogin,
        userPhone: this.createUserForm.value.userPhone,
        userEmail: this.createUserForm.value.userEmail,
        userPassword: this.createUserForm.value.userPassword,
        userRole: this.createUserForm.value.userRole,
        userRef: this.createUserForm.value.userRef,
        userType: this.createUserForm.value.userType,
      })
      .subscribe((user) => {
        if (user) {
          this.createUserForm.reset();
          this.router.navigate(["/users"]);
          this.us.getUsersList();
        }
      });
  }
```

When watching this block of code in the context of your implementation, we can see that each time when we create a new user we are creating a new `subscription`, which means that after we create our first user and we attempt to create a second one, we will be creating a new `subscription` executing the code inside the subscribe method + we will be also executing the code in the old `subscription`, because we never unsubscribe.

Also if we already had created a user we will get inside the `if(user)` block before creating successfully our new user, because we already have a user entity inside our store.

Refactored

```
user.service.ts

user$ = this.store.select(fromStore.getUserState);
userCreatedSuccesfuly$ = this.actions$.pipe(ofType(UserActions.USER_CREATE))
createUser(user: IUser): void {
    this.store.dispatch(new fromStore.UserCreate(user)); 
 }

user-create.component.ts

onCreateUser() {
    this.us
      .createUser({
        userLogin: this.createUserForm.value.userLogin,
        userPhone: this.createUserForm.value.userPhone,
        userEmail: this.createUserForm.value.userEmail,
        userPassword: this.createUserForm.value.userPassword,
        userRole: this.createUserForm.value.userRole,
        userRef: this.createUserForm.value.userRef,
        userType: this.createUserForm.value.userType,
      })
    this.us.userCreatedSuccesfuly$.pipe(take(1))
      .subscribe(() => {
          this.createUserForm.reset();
          this.router.navigate(["/users"]);
          this.us.getUsersList();
      });
  }
```

So the difference here is that now instead of depending on changes inside the user field (from the store) we are depending on the success action, that will be fired after a new user had been created, also by using the `take(1)` operator we are making sure that there will be no memory leaks because the subscription will be killed once that the user has been created.

(side-note: there is still the possibility of a memory leak if the user creation has failed, but I don't want to go in more complex solutions)

And now for the nested subscriptions

So overall `subscribe` inside of `subscribe` is a big no-no

```
this.us
      .createUser({
        userLogin: this.createContactUserForm.value.userPhone,
        userPhone: this.createContactUserForm.value.userPhone,
        userEmail: this.createContactUserForm.value.userEmail,
        userPassword: this.createContactUserForm.value.userPassword,
        userRole: this.createContactUserForm.value.userRole,
        userRef: this.createContactUserForm.value.userRef,
        userType: this.createContactUserForm.value.userType,
      })
      .subscribe((userState) => {
        if (userState.user) {
          this.cs
            .createContact({
              contactFirstName: this.createContactUserForm.value
                .contactFirstName,
              contactLastName: this.createContactUserForm.value.contactLastName,
              contactPatronymicName: this.createContactUserForm.value
                .contactPatronymicName,
              contactPhone: this.createContactUserForm.value.userPhone,
              contactUserId: userState.user._id,
            })
            .subscribe((contactState) => {
              if (contactState) {
                this.router.navigate(["/contacts"]);
              }
            });
        }
      });
```

Refactored

```
user.service.ts

user$ = this.store.select(fromStore.getUserState);
userCreatedSuccesfuly$ = this.actions$.pipe(ofType(UserActions.USER_CREATE_SUCCESS))
createUser(user: IUser): void {
    this.store.dispatch(new fromStore.UserCreate(user)); 
 }

contact.service.ts

contact$ = this.store.select(fromStore.getUserState);
contactCreatedSuccesfuly$ = this.actions$.pipe(ofType(ContactActions.CONTACT_CREATE_SUCCESS))
createUser(contact: IContact): void {
    this.store.dispatch(new fromStore.ContactCreate(contact)); 
 }

some-cmp.component.ts

doSomething(){

this.us.createUser({
        userLogin: this.createContactUserForm.value.userPhone,
        userPhone: this.createContactUserForm.value.userPhone,
        userEmail: this.createContactUserForm.value.userEmail,
        userPassword: this.createContactUserForm.value.userPassword,
        userRole: this.createContactUserForm.value.userRole,
        userRef: this.createContactUserForm.value.userRef,
        userType: this.createContactUserForm.value.userType,
      })

this.us.userCreatedSuccesfuly$.pipe(
      switchMap(() => this.us.user$),
      filter(x => !!x),
      tap(userState => {
         this.cs
            .createContact({
              contactFirstName: this.createContactUserForm.value
                .contactFirstName,
              contactLastName: this.createContactUserForm.value.contactLastName,
              contactPatronymicName: this.createContactUserForm.value
                .contactPatronymicName,
              contactPhone: this.createContactUserForm.value.userPhone,
              contactUserId: userState.user._id,
            })
      }),
      switchMap(() => this.cs.contactCreatedSuccesfuly$),
      take(1)
      )
      .subscribe((userState) => {
       this.router.navigate(["/contacts"]);
      });

}
```

So let us go through the last block of code:

- We create a new user
- `switchMap` We refer to `userCreatedSuccesfuly$` and we are saying, whenever this observable emits, switch to a new observable that is `this.us.users$`.
- `filter` Filter the passing values in such a way that only truthy values can pass trough the stream (e.g. only if there is a user saved inside in our store)
- `tap` Once a value reaches this point create a contact, by using the incoming value, without affecting the value of the current stream (e.g. create a contact with the user information)
- `switchMap` Here we are referring to the `this.us.users$` and we are saying whenever a value gets to this point, switch to a new observable that is `this.cs.contactCreatedSuccesfuly`
- `take` Here we make sure that we will clear our subscription after we have succeeded with the creation of new contact
- `subscribe` by calling this method we are triggering the stream

Oh boy, that was long, anyway, my advice to you is to spend some more time on learning `rxjs` in general